# How do I vertically center text in a button?

Tags: python, button, text, tkinter

I have a button within a frame:

`self.b = tk.Button(self.subframe1, text="UPDATE", command = self.update)`

The text in this button will be centered horizontally but not vertically. Is it possible to do the latter?

Comment: In my system button widget centers its text both horizontally and vertically by default.

Comment: According to [this page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method), the default for `anchor` is indeed `CENTER`...

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: And what platform are you on? I've seen differences in GUI appearance between Windows and OS X for the same exact code.

Comment: I'm on Linux (Fedora to be specific). Sorry I forgot the minimal example, I will do so when I'm back at my PC!

Comment: create screenshot to show how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @gandreadis, you can rely on [`anchor`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method) option to do the job.

Here is an MCVE (in Python 3.x):

```
import tkinter as tk


class Test:

   def __init__(self, master):
       self.master = master
       self.configure_gui()
       self.create_widgets()
       self.configure_widgets()

   def configure_gui(self):
       self.master.title("Button Text Centering")
       self.master.geometry('300x100')
       self.master.resizable(0, 0)

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.create_demo_button()

   def create_demo_button(self):
       self.btn_with_centered_text = tk.Button(self.master, text="Centered")
       self.btn_with_centered_text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
       self.btn_with_centered_text.config(bg="yellow")

   def configure_widgets(self):
       self.configure_btn_with_centered_text()

   def configure_btn_with_centered_text(self):
       self.btn_with_centered_text.config(bg="yellow", relief=tk.RAISED)
       self.btn_with_centered_text.config(border="2px")


def main():
   root = tk.Tk()
   t = Test(root)
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Demo:

[image]